# What is difference between getElementsByTagName() with tagName and with .//tagName?

Tags: c++, xml, getelementsbytagname, msxml6

What is difference between `getElementsByTagName()` with `tagName` and with `.//tagName` ?

When we pass tagname in the `getElementsByTagName()`, in that what is the meaning when we add ".//" ?

What is the difference between

`sSourceInputXml`->

```
getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t(".//author"), &xml2);
```

and

`sSourceInputXml`->

```
getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t("author"), &xml2);
```

?

Both return me same number of elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: xml library is msxml6.dll

Answer (score 0):

`//` means location step `descendant-or-self:node()`, which retrieves the current node and all its descendants.

`.` means `self::node()` which gets the context node.

Default location step is `child`, which gets the child elements of the context node.

If you need more information, check [here](http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/xmlnotes.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. But is there a difference if i use .//TagName and directly use TagName?  ie. directly use author as shown:  getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t("author"), &xml2);

Comment: @Veeru as far as I understand, no. Default mode returns children of context, and .// returns context nose and its children. So unless you are searching for context node itself (sounds unlikely) there will be no difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for a prompt response.